# Radio button does not get selected when I click on label

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, codeigniter-2

This is the markup:

```
<label for="big" class="labels">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="big" id="big"> Grandes images
</label>
```

It's generated by this:

```
<?php
    $radio_data = array('id'=>'big','name'=>'type','type'=>'radio','value'=>'big');
    echo form_label(form_input($radio_data)." Petites images\n",'small', $label_data);
?>
```

When I click on the label, normally the radio button gets selected but that did not happen. I'm using **twitter bootstrap.**

**EDIT:**

New HTML:

```
<span>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="small" id="small">
   <label for="small" class="labels radio"> Petites images</label>
</span>
```

New PHP:

```
<?php
    echo form_input($radio1_data);
    echo form_label(" Petites images", 'small', $label_data);
?>
```

but, still when click on the label the radio does not get selected.

Comment: try like this https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete

Answer (score 0):

Your passing in the `form_input()` as an argument to [form_label()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) which is not correct as `form_label()` takes these arguments:

`form_label($label_text = '', $id = '', $attributes = array())`

**Try changing this:**

```
echo form_label(form_input($radio_data)." Petites images\n",'small', $label_data);
```

**To:**

```
echo form_input($radio_data) . form_label(" Petites images\n", $radio_data['id'], $label_data);
```

Output should end up like:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="big" id="big">
<label for="big" class="labels"> Petites images</label>
```

Comment: @YahyaKACEM Any chance you have a demo url?

Comment: @YahyaKACEM In reference to your update, you should being using a `<div>` wrapper instead of a `<span>` wrapper since span tags can only contain other inline elements like abbr, strong, etc... Please refer to: http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/bltags_span.htm

Comment: no, is twitter bootstrap have any effect on that functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know php but i do know html.

Try to bring an output like this:

```
<label for="big" class="labels">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="big" id="big">
    <i>Grandes Images</i>   
</label>
```

Twitter boostrap does not have anything to do with this issue.

Answer (score -1):

That's not valid HTML. The label does not contain the input, they are separated and connected by `id` on input and `for` on label. Look up the [spec](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp).

Comment: This is incorrect. See a better reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Using_the_.22for.22_attribute